# XML Parse node value not working in IE

Tags: javascript, xml, browser

I have an XML and when I parse it and try to get the node value it works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. Please suggest .

```
var txt = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n<info>\n<error>\n<code>0</code>\n<name>STATUS_OK</name>\n</error>\n</info>\n";
var errCode = xmlDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].children[0].innerHTML;
```

In Firefox errCode is `0`, whereas it gives an error in IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code, it works both in IE and other browsers.

```js
var xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n<info>\n<error>\n<code>0</code>\n<name>STATUS_OK</name>\n</error>\n</info>\n";

if (window.DOMParser){
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
} else {
    // Internet Explorer
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(xmlString);
}

//check if tag is present otherwise assign empty string "" ;
var code = (typeof(xml.getElementsByTagName("code")[0]) !== "undefined") ? xml.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].textContent : "";   

//check if tag is present otherwise assign empty string "" ;
var message = (typeof(xml.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]) !== "undefined") ? xml.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent : ""; 

alert("code : "+code+"\nname : "+message);
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me... One more help if you can do. What should i do if i have to check if Node name "code" exist in xml then only find out the value.

Comment: @AbhinavParashar , I've edited the answer as you said in comment 
, check if tag exist , then get value otherwise value will be empty string

Comment: So please mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer ) ( like in this image => [image resolve post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thank you .